# Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.8.7

Please help me out with this, jquery is working well in w3schools but in my rails 2 app its getting error like check not defined 
Here is my html code:

```
Checkbox: <input class="category_select" title="3" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="6"/>

<input class="category_select" title="9" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="7"/>

<input class="category_select" title="6" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="8"/>
```

and the Jquery as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js">
  function check(val,that) {
    var total=parseInt(0,10);
    $('.category_select').each(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')==true)
        total=total+parseInt($(this).attr('title'),10);
    });
    if (total > val){
      $(that).removeAttr('checked');
      alert('Total is greater than val !');

    }else{
      alert('Total is less than or equal to val !');
    }
  }
</script>
```

The above code works well , but when i insert it into my rails app its getting error , I dont know where I am going wrong.
Any help is valuable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in rails 2 JQUERY is not supporting so i changed my script to Javascript as follows

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function check_total(e,t){ 
value=parseInt(e);
var a=parseInt(0);
$$("input.category_select").each(function(e){1==e.checked&&(a+=parseInt(e.title))}),a>value?(alert("Total is greater than Total Subcategory Hours !"),t.checked=!1):a==value&&alert("Total is equal to Total Subcategory Hours !")}
</script>
```

Thanks for your answers. the above script worked for me

Answer (score 2):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block for your jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function check(val, that) {
      var total = parseInt(0, 10);
      $('.category_select').each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked') == true)
              total = total + parseInt($(this).attr('title'), 10);
      });
      if (total > val) {
          $(that).removeAttr('checked');
          alert('Total is greater than val !');

      } else {
          alert('Total is less than or equal to val !');
      }
  }

  $(function() {
      $(document).on('change', '.category_select', function() {
          check(11, this);
      });
  });
</script>
```

As you are using jQuery bind event handlers using it.

Comment: @HemanthMC, get rid of inline click handler and try updated code

Comment: what went wrong in my script?? plz can you help me out

Comment: @HemanthMC, I have not modified your script at all, just binded event using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

1.Your script isn't loading properly.
2.You loaded script is not present in document scope.

**Note : You have to use separate scripts tags to load external JS files and to write JS code.**

try like this

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function check(val, that) {
      var total = parseInt(0, 10);
      $('.category_select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') == true)
          total = total + parseInt($(this).attr('title'), 10);
      });
      if (total > val) {
        $(that).removeAttr('checked');
        alert('Total is greater than val !');

      } else {
        alert('Total is less than or equal to val !');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  Checkbox:
  <input class="category_select" title="3" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="6" />

  <input class="category_select" title="9" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="7" />

  <input class="category_select" title="6" name="subject_ids[]" onchange="check(11,this)" type="checkbox" value="8" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but even after i tried your script i am getting the same error

Comment: load your script that contains `check` function in head tag and try

Comment: sorry i am not getting can you please help me how to load that check function in head tag

Comment: you have the head tag in your html page right ? now just place the above `script ` content including tags in before closing head tag .

Comment: i updated my code as i said , seeing that you can change

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you are defining your function to the scope of DOM Ready Event.....
Instead of that try to define your function outside the scope of Function.